# facebook october 2013 migration affects likes.count field in Graph Api call

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, joomla, facebook-javascript-sdk

When i enable migration to october 2013, likes.count field is not seen for each post of fb page/group by Graph Api feed call.So this field per post will be permanently removed from Graph api call like pageid/feed?limit=20 on october.
But i show this feed in many websites with how many total likes per post.so then i have to find alternatives,so is i got through google.com that -

> It's needed to have another Graph api or fql query call for likes count per post along with the first call for page feed

so if it's possible to know likes count per post in only one Graph Api call, then tell me or what is the correct way to go for another Graph Api,Fql query call for all likes count per post?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have loaded the Facebook page feed:

```
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = your_app_id;
    $config['secret'] = your_secret_number;
    $confif['fileUpload'] = false;
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $pageid = facebook_page_id;
    $pagefeed = $facebook->api('/' . $pageid . '/feed');
```

You can loop through the data and find a field called 'likes'.
With an other loop you can get the total number of likes for the corresponding post.
If you want the number of likes for a posted comment there is also a field called 'like_count'
that directly gives the number of likes for this comment.

Retrieving likes count per post :

```
    foreach ($pagefeed['data'] as $post)
    {
        $likes_number = 0;
        if (isset($post['likes']))
        {
            foreach ($post['likes']['data'] as $like)
                $likes_number++;
        }
    }
```

Retrieving likes count for each comment :

```
    if (isset($post['comments']))
    {
        foreach ($post['comments']['data'] as $comment)
        {
            echo $comment['like_count'];
        }
    }
```